How to prevent a module in react (e.g: export function() {} ...) inside a custom component library to be importable outside the library
I have created a sharable react component library with a demo components showing how to use each component. Those components are exported so that they can be added to the route for the demoPage, but I do not want them to be importable by client projects. How can I achieve that
